# VHDL: Is alias only used to refer to subset of std_logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl

I have seen alias declared to control subset of a big std_logic_vector. What are other applications of it?

Comment: It's a purely syntactic construct. And as one it used used to improve the visual appearance of the code to improve readability and self-documentation.

Comment: Any time you want to simplify the name of something of any datatype

Comment: I guess it only works with signals in the most tools. Setting aliasses for a function maybe work onl in simulators :).

Comment: ok. I want to have a name for a type which is an integer between 0 and 99 so I don't have to write "integer range 0 to 99" every time. Should this be created using alias or using type or subtype?

Comment: Besides this, should only the base object be included in the sensitivity list or the alias objects associated with it as well or both?

Comment: Some more examples can be found [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/aliasdec.html). If you need an `integer range 0 to 99` then declare it as sub-type. I have used `alias` long time ago, but experienced trouble with my synthesis tools. Haven't tried it with modern tools. Not sure, if this is worth an answer.